# A query for finding the nearest free time slot in mysql - why it doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `notes` and there I have three fields:

```
id  |      start_time       |  duration
 1  |  2015-10-21 19:41:35  |    15
 2  |  2015-10-21 19:41:50  |    15
 3  |  2015-10-21 19:42:05  |    15
 4  |  2015-10-21 19:42:35  |    15
etc.
```

`id` is INT field

`start_time` is a TIMESTAMP field

`duration` is INT field that tells the number of seconds of how long each event is.

I'm writing an SQL query that will get the 3 fields as an input: `duration`, `begin_time` and `end_time` and will return me a `timestamp` field of where exactly new even can fit.

Based on lots of questions similar to mine on StackOverflow (mostly this particular one [MySQL / PHP - Find available time slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414795/mysql-php-find-available-time-slots) ) I created a query:

```
SELECT (a.start_time + a.duration) AS free_after FROM notes a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM notes b
WHERE b.start_time BETWEEN (a.start_time+a.duration) AND
(a.start_time+a.duration) + INTERVAL '$duration' SECOND) AND 
(a.start_time+a.duration) BETWEEN '$begin_time' AND '$end_time'
```

But when I run it as follows:

```
SELECT (a.start_time + a.duration) AS free_after FROM notes a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM notes b WHERE b.start_time
BETWEEN (a.start_time+a.duration) AND (a.start_time+a.duration) + INTERVAL 15 SECOND )
AND (a.start_time+a.duration) BETWEEN '2015-11-21 19:41:30' AND '2015-11-21 19:43:50'
```

I get no records found, even though - looking at the table mentioned above - I should get a result:

```
     free_after 
2015-11-21 19:42:20
```

(because between those two records:

```
 3  |  2015-10-21 19:42:05  |    15
 4  |  2015-10-21 19:42:35  |    15
```

there is a free slot of 15 seconds). So why does my query not work properly?

==== EDIT:

After following Richard's advice I did a `show warnings` query and it returned me the values:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2015-11-21 19:4...
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2015-11-21 19:4...
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2015-11-21 19:4...
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2015-11-21 19:4...
Incorrect datetime value: '0'
```

and I'm not sure what causes it, could you help me with that?

===== EDIT 2

Okay, after following another @Richard's advice (thanks btw!) I changed my query to the following one:

```
SELECT (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AS free_after FROM notes a
WHERE
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM notes b WHERE b.start_time
BETWEEN (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AND
(a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) + INTERVAL 15 SECOND ) AND
(a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) BETWEEN '2015-11-21 19:41:30' AND '2015-11-21 19:43:50'
```

and this time I got a result (Which is a good message):

```
2015-10-21 19:42:50
```

but it's a bad value (which is a worse message). It should be `2015-10-21 19:42:20`... Is there anything else that I'm doing wrong here? When I do `show warnings` right after it - there's nothing more here :(

Comment: After trying the select query, it should report 8 warnings - if you then do `show warnings;` it lists issues with your query.

Comment: Thanks @Richard for your suggestion, I wrote the show warnings and now I see exactly what's going on, but I don't know what might be the exact problem here. I suspect it's the issue that the `start_time` field is a timestamp and I probably have to modify my query to operate on timestamps and not on date time, but I don't know exactly how to fix it, could you help me with that? Please check my edit to the original question, thanks!

Comment: The truncated incorrect double value is because you are adding an int (the duration column) to a timestamp, so mysql converts the result to a double but then gets confused. If you try `a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND` that fixes most of the warnings.

Comment: Thank you @Richard for your answer, again :). I followed your advices, but I'm still struggling with one issue, could you please check my 2nd edit?

Comment: Another typo in your query - the final BETWEEN has 2 dates for november rather than october (11 rather than 10), but your sample dates are in october! Still that only returns the 19:42:50 answer which is correct (given corrected between dates), but also not the only answer!

Comment: The problem for your expected answer is that BETWEEN matches upto and including the end date, so effectively it rules out row id=4 because you add the row 3 duration of 15 seconds to the fixed interval of 15 seconds, to row 3 start time which then equals the row 4 start time, so your subselect matches and rules out row 3 as a potential source for a gap. Try changing the fixed interval to 14 and you get the expected answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BETWEEN` clause matches the end dates exactly. With your sample data, once you add the duration of 15 seconds and the fixed duration, also of 15 seconds, it matches your last sample data that is 30 seconds on, and hence rules out. Modify your query to

```sql
SELECT (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AS free_after FROM notes a
WHERE
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM notes b WHERE b.start_time
BETWEEN (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AND
(a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) + INTERVAL 15 SECOND - INTERVAL 1 MICROSECOND) AND
(a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) BETWEEN '2015-10-21 19:41:30' AND '2015-10-21 19:43:50'
```

(i.e. taking off 1 microsecond as an adjustment)

and you get the answer:

```
+---------------------+
| free_after          |
+---------------------+
| 2015-10-21 19:42:20 |
| 2015-10-21 19:42:50 |
+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Because you can't just add `TIMESTAMP` to `INT`.

See for example: [How to add an offset to all timestamps/DATETIME in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077074/how-to-add-an-offset-to-all-timestamps-datetime-in-a-mysql-database)

Long answer:

As a general rule when debugging a complicated SQL query, start from a simpler form and then add your more complex clauses one by one until it stops doing what you expect, then fix that.  In your case, start with

```
SELECT (a.start_time + a.duration) AS free_after FROM notes a;
```

Which when I try it on my system gives:

```
+----------------+
| free_after     |
+----------------+
| 20151021194150 |
| 20151021194165 |
| 20151021194220 |
| 20151021190250 |
+----------------+
```

Those don't look like normal `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` values to me.  I notice that in one place your query does use the `INTERVAL <value> SECOND` notation to add an offset to a `TIMESTAMP`, but this neglected in all the other additions.

```
mysql> SELECT (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AS free_after FROM notes a;
+---------------------+
| free_after          |
+---------------------+
| 2015-10-21 19:41:50 |
| 2015-10-21 19:42:05 |
| 2015-10-21 19:42:20 |
| 2015-10-21 19:02:50 |
+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That looks better.  Following the same principle throughout, the full query gives the expected result.

Also, as Richard commented, you should have seen warnings reported.  Using `show warnings;` in mysql would then have given you a similar clue by complaining about "Incorrect datetime value" and "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value".

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed your and Richard's advice, and I went a little bit further, but still there is some error in my query, I edited the question for the 2nd time, could you take a look at it and tell me what might be wrong there?

Comment: @user3766930 Looking again, your queries and data seem to be mixed up on whether the date should be in October or November.  With the data you quoted originally and your Edit 2 query adjusted to use October, I get `2015-10-21 19:42:20`, so something must be different on your side?

Comment: @user3766930 Oh... I just saw you also edited the table data to change the last row from 19:02:35 to 19:42:35, so 19:42:50 is a correct solution.  The reason you're not getting 19:42:20 is that `BETWEEN` is *inclusive*.  Your `NOT EXISTS` clause removes it because 19:42:20 plus 15 seconds equals 19:42:35, which exists in your table already.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an int to a date. Try this:

```
    SELECT notes.starttime+ INTERVAL notes.duration SECOND
FROM notes
WHERE notes.starttime+INTERVAL notes.duration SECOND<= '2015-11-21 19:41:30'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT notes.id 
      FROM notes 
      WHERE notes.starttime <= '2015-11-21 19:43:50'
        AND notes.starttime+ INTERVAL notes.duration SECOND>='2015-11-21 19:43:50')
ORDER BY notes.starttime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the LAG() function and...:

- First. Calculate the difference between the current row and the last one
- Second. Select rows with diff bigger than duration

Try this SQL:

```
SET @lag_time='0000-00-00 00:00:00';
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD( SECOND, duration, lastTime ) as fromTime,
       (diffTime - duration) freeSeconds,
       currTime toTime
FROM
  (SELECT @lag_time as LastTime, 
         IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @lag_time, start_time ),0) diffTime,
         @lag_time:=start_time currTime,
         duration       
  FROM notes) as TimeDiff
WHERE diffTime > duration
ORDER BY currTime;
```