# I have an sql query for finding a nearest free time after specific date. How can I make it to also look for a date BEFORE this date?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a follow up to my previous question [A query for finding the nearest free time slot in mysql - why it doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688658/a-query-for-finding-the-nearest-free-time-slot-in-mysql-why-it-doesnt-work/)

Basically I have a table:

```
id  |      start_time       |  duration
 1  |  2015-10-21 19:41:35  |    15
 2  |  2015-10-21 19:41:50  |    15
 3  |  2015-10-21 19:42:05  |    15
 4  |  2015-10-21 19:42:35  |    15
etc.
```

and it contains the event start_time and its duration. I asked for help with finding the nearest time slot in which the event can be placed between the existing events. @Richard came up with a perfect answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33689786/3766930 and suggested a query:

```
SELECT (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AS free_after FROM notes a
WHERE
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM notes b WHERE b.start_time
BETWEEN (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AND
(a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) + INTERVAL 15 SECOND - INTERVAL 1 MICROSECOND) AND
(a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) BETWEEN '2015-10-21 19:41:30' AND '2015-10-21 19:43:50'
```

which works great.

Now I was wondering if there's a possibility of finding a most suitable date not only between the existing dates, but also right before them.

For example: I would set a begin_date as `2015-10-21 16:00:00` and end_date as `2015-10-21 21:00:00`. Currently the result of @Richard's query would be `2015-10-21 19:42:20`. But is there a way of creating a query that in this result will return `2015-10-21 19:41:20` as the closest one to the first date that is already in database?

Comment: It looks like you want to find the next-earliest entry based on a duration of 15.  Is the duration always going to be 15, or do you need to be able to specify a different duration?  (Aside: Why even have a "duration" field if it is always and forever the same value?)

Comment: Also, do you need to guard against overlap?  That is, start_time from one note can't be before start_time + interval from the previous?  If so I will need to modify my answer.

Comment: Hey @Lotharyx, yes, the duration might be different, sorry for not mentioning that.. Also, as for your 2nd question - the answer is Yes, I need to guard against overlap. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Offhand I'm not entirely sure that can be done with a simple statement, due to the need to check for overlapping events outside the original search window.  Since you can't possibly know what the duration of the potentially-overlapping earlier event is without reading it, it would require some sequence of selects of indeterminate number.  This may only be achievable through a stored procedure or external client code.  I'll keep pondering it, though.

Comment: I don't understand the arithmetic of the desired result :-(

Comment: I agree with Strawberry, your title says nearest free time before a specific date, so I don't understand why 19:41:20 is better than 19:42:20?

Comment: Also how do you even land on 19:41:20? There is no row in your table that would indicate that time is available, unless you're counting 15 seconds before the first time which doesn't sound like a stable method, since duration isn't *always* 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution for this would be to use date_sub with an order by statement, limiting the results to show only 1 record.

This is the result:

```
SELECT date_sub(start_time, interval duration second) as free_before FROM `notes` where start_time>'2015-10-21 16:00:00' order by start_time asc limit 1
```

**Bonus for you**

Using the previous solution @Richard provided. Putting it all together to show all free times in 1 table could result in the following:

```
select * from (SELECT date_sub(start_time, interval duration second) as free_times FROM `notes` where start_time>'2015-10-21 16:00:00' order by start_time asc limit 1) a
union
(SELECT (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AS free_times FROM notes a
WHERE
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM notes b WHERE b.start_time
BETWEEN (a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) AND
(a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) + INTERVAL 15 SECOND - INTERVAL 1 MICROSECOND) AND
(a.start_time + INTERVAL a.duration SECOND) BETWEEN '2015-10-21 19:41:30' AND '2015-10-21 19:43:50')
```

**Edit:**

I will only write my part of the query. The other part was working correctly and only if you want me to change it I will (never fix something that ain't broke)

If you want interval of 10 seconds ->

```
SELECT date_sub(start_time, interval 10 second) as free_times FROM `notes` where start_time>'2015-10-21 16:00:00' order by start_time asc limit 1
```

If you want interval of 15 seconds ->

```
SELECT date_sub(start_time, interval 15 second) as free_times FROM `notes` where start_time>'2015-10-21 16:00:00' order by start_time asc limit 1
```

In this case you'll have to change your start_time and the duration accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @davejal, it almost works.. The problem is that in your query when I look for events before the existing one then I'm taking wrong duration time (not the one given by me but the one assigned to the existing one). For example, I have in my database times: `22:00:00` with duration `10`, `22:00:10` with duration `15` and now when I try to look for another free time for duration `15` I'm getting the time `21:59:50` instead of `21:59:45`. Do you know what might be wrong here?

Comment: in that case you will have to pass the duration you want also and place it in the date_sub replacing duration with that amount. See my edit for a better explaination

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

Given:

```
select * from notes;
+----+---------------------+----------+
| id | start_time          | duration |
+----+---------------------+----------+
|  1 | 2015-11-17 10:10:10 |       15 |
|  2 | 2015-11-17 10:20:40 |       15 |
|  3 | 2015-11-17 10:30:00 |       15 |
+----+---------------------+----------+
```

This result:

```
select (start_time - interval 15 second) as earlier_date
    from notes
    where start_time > '2015-11-17 10:15:00' 
       AND start_time < '2015-11-17 10:25:00' 
    order by start_time 
    limit 1;

+---------------------+
| earlier_date        |
+---------------------+
| 2015-11-17 10:20:25 |
+---------------------+
```

**Important:** This sample doesn't pay any attention to entries that might fall immediately in front of the search window (because your example didn't include any).  This query as-is *will* create overlaps if there are impinging entries just prior to the search window.

Answer (score -2):

Take your base table and insert a fake row that is the minimum start time and subtract 15 seconds.

So instead of notes, use a subquery like this:

```
    SELECT 
            MIN(start_time) - INTERVAL 15 seconds AS start_time,
            0 AS duration
    FROM notes

    UNION ALL

    SELECT start_time, duration
    FROM notes
```

Comment: You're suggesting he insert fake data into the table?  How would any other consumer of the table know the data was fake?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting they use a subquery that inserts a dummy row so it looks like there's a row before all the other data. Perhaps it was worded incorrectly. Wherever they currently reference the notes table in the query, they would use the subquery in my post instead.

Comment: Oh, I get it.  But, your suggestion does not take into account the asker's need to specify a window of time (begin_date and end_date).  Your example would always return the very earliest position of the entire data set.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I believe that's what they intended for. If it's not, it could be modified to include a where clause in the MIN() query so the dummy record is created for the earliest of those in the chosen time frame.